# How to do a OneToOne relation using Exposed

Tags: kotlin, orm, dsl, one-to-one

I'm trying to do a OneToOne relation between two tables using Exposed, I've created a User table and a UserSettings Table, I'd like to have the User table reference the UserSettings table. My question is how do I create the reference and create a user that has referenced settings?

UserTable

```
object UserTable : IntIdTable("user") {
    val username = varchar("username", 16)
    val email = varchar("email", 254)
    val password = varchar("password_hash", 60)
    val settings = reference("id", UserSettingsTable)
}
```

UserEntity

```
class User(id: EntityID<Int>): IntEntity(id), Principal {

    companion object : IntEntityClass<User>(UserTable)

    var username by UserTable.username
    var email by UserTable.email
    var password by UserTable.password
    val settings by UserSettings referrersOn UserTable.settings
}
```

SettingsTable

```
object UserSettingsTable : IntIdTable("user_settings") {
    var themeName = varchar("theme_name", 16).clientDefault {"dark"}
}
```

SettingsEntity

```
open class UserSettings(id: EntityID<Int>) : IntEntity(id) {

    companion object : IntEntityClass<UserSettings>(UserSettingsTable)

    var themeName by UserSettingsTable.themeName
}
```

This is what I was attempting to do to create an entry

```
User.new {
    email = "email@gmail.com"
    username = "Someone"
    password = "test"
}.also { newUser ->
    UserSettings.new(newUser.id.value) {
        themeName = "dark"
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you put the user id into the user settings constructor? Make the `User#settings` writable and assign a new `UserSettings` object there

Comment: You  cannot use a var with referrersOn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a sample that I haven't tested:

```
object UserSettingsTable : IntIdTable("user_settings") {
    var themeName = varchar("theme_name", 16).clientDefault {"dark"}
}

object UserTable : IntIdTable("user") {
    val username = varchar("username", 16)
    val email = varchar("email", 254)
    val password = varchar("password_hash", 60)
    val settings = reference("settings", UserSettingsTable)
}

class UserSettings(id: EntityID<Int>) : IntEntity(id) {

    companion object : IntEntityClass<UserSettings>(UserSettingsTable)

    var themeName by UserSettingsTable.themeName
}

class User(id: EntityID<Int>): IntEntity(id) {

    companion object : IntEntityClass<User>(UserTable)

    var username by UserTable.username
    var email by UserTable.email
    var password by UserTable.password
    var settings by UserSettings referencedOn UserTable.settings
}

fun createUser(): User {
    return User.new(1) {
        email = "email@gmail.com"
        username = "Someone"
        password = "test"
        settings = UserSettings.new(1) { themeName = "dark" }
    }
}
```

Mind that `referencedOn` is for simple references, while `referrersOn` is for collections. Also, there is [a limitation](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/wiki/DAO#many-to-many-reference) in the Exposed

> Creating the entity and the reference in the same transaction does only work if you set the id column manually. If you're using UUIDTables and UUIDEntity you can do it like this:

```
transaction {
 //only works with UUIDTable and UUIDEntity
 StarWarsFilm.new (UUID.randomUUID()){
    ...
    actors = SizedCollection(listOf(actor))
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work, for the id I'm creating a create method in the companion object and using count() + 1 to get the next id

the code snippet is too long for a comment so if you want to look at it
https://media.marshallwalker.ca/05a014e0

Comment: One of the issues I've run into is that i cannot call user.settings without being in a new transaction? I'm using ktor and passing the User as a Principal then just responding to the call with user.settings.themeName but it's complaining that it's not in a transaction

https://media.marshallwalker.ca/8f66e581

Comment: Yes, accessing entity properties outside of a transaction is not safe